# Look up serial number of an apple device I used to have?

Tags: icloud, serial-number

I used to have multiple ipads. Heavily used icloud with all of them and through out time sold them out after some use. Recently had to list the serial numbers of the apple devices I had over years and was wondring. Since I no longer own the devices, nor the boxes/receipts for them is there a way I can look up their serial numbers?

Comment: If you no longer own them or have any of the boxes or receipts, why do you need the serial numbers?

Comment: I sold my last ipad yesterday adn I thought that I bought it from apple store and had email receipt on my email, so I told the buyer that. he asked for it adn I realised that I bought in an airport from some tech shop and could not really prove that it wasn't stolen. I thought I could look it up somehow using serial number